# terminating with uncaught exception when i use UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, error-handling

[image]

```
@IBAction func onlytest(_ sender: Any) {

        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self

        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Choose image source", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera roll", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { ( alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
            self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } ))

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Take Photo", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { ( alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
            self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } ))

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))

        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)



    }
```

When I click take photo I get the following error:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" crash the app

However when I click Camera roll it works.

There is no error in connection. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You need to update your question with the rest of the error message and clearly point out which line of code exactly is causing the crash.

Comment: Are you trying this code on Simulator? Camera only works with a device.

Comment: You need a description in your info.plist if you haven't already done so to tell the app what message to display when it tries to ask for camera permission. It is mandatory in newer versions of iOS. Add a key of `Privacy - Camera Usage Description` and a string description to achieve that.

Comment: i added Key       :  Privacy - Camera Usage Description   
Value   :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) camera use